# How to show backward counting in TOAST until process in "Timer" gets executed

Tags: android

I am running a timer task and executing a process it in. Now until the timer gets executed is there any way to show countdown (backward counting) seconds in TOAST message so that user will be aware of how much time process is going to take ?

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    //Execute Process
                                }
                                }, 20000);  //After 20 seconds*/
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congratulations!! Process Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Use Dialog for this.Toast will be shown for limited period of time.

Comment: Thanks Kalyan, how can i do that with Dialog, U have example code ?

Answer (score 0):

For count down timers, a `CountDownTimer` is a good choise:

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000 * 1000 + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congratulations!! Process Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}.start();
```

Please note, that the above is only an example, and output could need to be adjusted (`onTick()` method is fired not on the exact millis time, and system also needs time to execute the code)

Comment: Thanks Alexander Zhak, But How do I synchronise this "countdown timer" with my "timer task" ?

Comment: `CountDownTimer` is a replacement for `TimerTask`

Comment: Ok, Great and where do i execute my code ? "onTick" ? I hope this won't block UI and i won't get "ANR" messages

Comment: In onTick(), yes. But it may cause ANR. This class is not intended for heavy computations. Or could be moved out of the UI thread